# I want to put a gallery view at the 4 th position of a list view

Tags: android, listview, galleryview

and my list view is a list fragment list view because it is in view pager how to do it.
my all normal rows have 10 text views and at 4th position i want to show a scroll view horizontal i.e. gallery view with image and text all data is in form of json and normally every things works fine but I can't put a gallery view inside it please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since GalleryView is deprecated I had used View pager for Image and text at the fourth position I returned different view type for the row item in the list view